# Adding file to jlist

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Adding file to jlist, I add to jframe, one jbutton, one jtextview and one jlist, I add file .txt but effectlly to jtextview ex: C:/Windows/file.txt

```
JList.add(JList, null);
```

But theres something went wrong

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the List Model for your JList. You can't just directly add to a JList like you've done since the JList is so versatile to handle all sorts of Objects. It's a little more complicated than that.

First you want to make sure your JList actually contains a Default List Model:

```
// Make sure the JList contains a List Model
try { 
    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel)yourJListName.getModel(); 
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Nope...so let's set one.
    yourJListName.setModel(new DefaultListModel()); 
}
```

Now that your sure your JList contains a List Model you can add items to it.

```
// Get the current List Model for your JList
DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel)yourJListName.getModel();
// Declare a list to represent it.
JList list = new JList(dlm);
// Get the last position within the List so
// as to append to it.
int pos = list.getModel().getSize();
// Add the text from the JTextField into your JList.
dlm.add(pos, yourJTextFieldName.getText());
```

Perhaps create a Method to do the adding for you:

```
public void addToJList(JList yourJList, String stringToAdd) {
    // Make sure the JList contains a List Model
    try { 
        DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel)yourJList.getModel(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Nope...so let's set one.
        yourJList.setModel(new DefaultListModel()); 
    }

    // Get the current List Model for your JList
    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel)yourJList.getModel();
    // Declare a list to represent it.
    JList list = new JList(dlm);
    // Get the last position within the List so
    // as to append to it.
    int pos = list.getModel().getSize();
    // Add the text from the JTextField into your JList.
    dlm.add(pos, stringToAdd);
}
```

And how you might use it:

```
addToJList(yourJListName, yourJTextFieldName.getText());
```

Comment: Im push the jbutton then want to add files to jlist and the effectlly to jtextview ex : C:/Windows/text.txt

Comment: @kasimirus - That comment might really mean something to you but it means absolutely nothing to me. What files are you talking about? Could it be that you want to display the **file path** (C:\Windows.file.txt) within the JList and upon selection of that item within the JList you want the file contents displayed within the JTextView? Which brings me to another question....What JTextView? Which platform are you working in. Is this for Android?

Comment: this is for desktop apps c:/Windows/text.txt its a location files and input to jlist example. 300, 400, 500, etc

Comment: So it is the file contents you want to be displayed within the JList, am I right? If so show an example of the text contained within the file (a few lines) within your original post. Then....create a new post: "How to read a Text File"!

Comment: the question as the same but not the pointed. By the way well I cant be reading txt files in java. Can u must the code right now